# React Native <Text> Changing 'fff' to Strange Line Symbol?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, formatting, native

I am using react native to render some text in a flatlist from firebase.
Whenever I have text with 'fff' in it it changes it to a weird vertical line symbol.

I have no idea how to fix this issue, I made sure the text was a proper string. Outside of that I have no idea how to get rid of this weird formatting issue.

[image: image with weird formatting in the text element]

```
<View style={[styles.row, {padding: 0, marginBottom: 100, marginTop: 0}]}>
      <FlatList
        data={dbStoryEntries}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title}
        columnWrapperStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
          <View
            style={{
              height: Dimensions.get('screen').width / 2 + 15, //8
            }}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => this.navigateTo(item.title)}>
              <View
                style={{
                  padding: 20,
                }}>
                <NeuView
                  inset
                  color="#f0f0f0"
                  height={Dimensions.get('screen').width / 2 - 40}
                  width={Dimensions.get('screen').width / 2 - 40}
                  borderRadius={10}
                  style={{marginTop: 0, paddingBottom: 5}}>
                  <Image
                    fluid
                    source={{uri: this.state.images[index]}}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    style={{flex: 1, width: '99.9%', borderRadius: 10}}
                  />
                </NeuView>
                <Text
                  width={80}
                  style={[
                    styles.nexaDark,
                    {
                      fontSize: 18,
                      marginTop: 0,
                      opacity: 0.5,
                      textAlign: 'center',
                    },
                  ]}>
                  {item.title}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
```

styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nexaDark: {
    fontFamily: 'NexaTextDemo-Bold',
    color: '#696766',
  },
  nexaLight: {
    fontFamily: 'NexaTextDemo-Bold',
    color: '#838180',
  },
```

Comment: What happens when you replace {item.title} for 'testfff' ?

Comment: Surprisingly, same exact thing. Still the weird symbol in there.
https://imgur.com/a/sit8VCf

Comment: give a console.log of the dbStoryEntries please

Comment: Had to JSON.stringify here it is un-stringified too: https://imgur.com/a/TKnLWTK
Must be confusing to read, since the key is title too

Comment: I just noticed you're using a custom font. Try removing your fontFamily. Maybe there is a bug with it.